# Identifying unknown chip - markings erased

Tags: hardware, embedded, physical-attacks

There seems to be a (relatively) easy way to [remove the markings on a chip via laser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yGWuUFiFEI). When reverse engineering a device with such a chip, what would be some methods of identifying it.

It seems that package type and number of pins can help, are there any other methods that can be used?

Is it possible to image the chip in some way that would reveal what was erased?